# JHipster OneToMany relations don't show up in the front-end as lists

Tags: spring, jhipster

So I created a monolith (Spring+Angular) with JHipster 7.8.1 CLI, then proceeded to add 2 entities with the CLI too, I first created **Author**, then created **Book** and specified its *ManyToOne* relation to **Author**, then modified **Author** to add the *OneToMany* relation on the other end (I cannot add *ManyToOne* while creating **Author** since it will look for the **Book** entity which isn't created yet and would therefor raise an error).

The *ManyToOne* relation works fine on the front-end, I can see the *author* field in the **Book** entity, and can select one when editing/creating a book. However on the other hand the *OneToMany* relation doesn't seem to work, I cannot see the list of books of each author nor edit/add one or multiple books to an author.

Am I doing something wrong or do I need to modify the front-end code to enable this feature?

EDIT: the list of books of an author does fill on the server-side, this can be verified with the Rest API (*/api/authors*), the *books* field is returned and has the related books.

Comment: By looking at generator's entity details template, I think that JHipster generates a UI only for the owner side. See https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/blob/main/generators/entity-client/templates/angular/src/main/webapp/app/entities/list/entity-management.component.html.ejs#L85-L90

Comment: Thanks! I will manually add that to the UI code since the Rest API returns the list of books.